# Bind count of pushpins on the Map to TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

I have two controls in a Stack Panel - Map and TextBlock. Collection of pushpins on a map changes dynamically. So I need TextBlock to display current Count of items in pushpins collection. 
  What is a right approach to bind ItemsSource.Length to TextBlock.Text? Somehow like this:

```
<maps:Map Name="MainMap">
     <toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
         <toolkit:MapItemsControl Name="BusItems">
              <toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <toolkit:Pushpin GeoCoordinate="{Binding Coordinates}" Content="{Binding Value}"/>
                   </DataTemplate>
              </toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         </toolkit:MapItemsControl>
     </toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
</maps:Map>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=BusItems}"></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind to Items.Count, because it is a method not a property, so create a property exposing Items.Count() like so:

```
public int PushpinCount
{
    get { return Items.Count(); }
}
```

and bind to PushpinCount instead.